# LSF - Get ID of submitted job

Tags: lsf

Say I submit a job using something like `bsub pwd`. Now I would like to get the job ID of that job in order to build a dependency for the next job. Is there some way I can get bsub to return the job ID?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as a reference, this is the best solution I could come up with so far. It takes advantage of the fact that bsub write a line containing the ID to STDOUT.

```
function nk_jobid {
    output=$($*)
    echo $output | head -n1 | cut -d'<' -f2 | cut -d'>' -f1
}
```

Usage:

```
jobid=$(nk_jobid bsub pwd)
```

Comment: @AndreyRubshtein thats bash.

Comment: I'm wondering how to pass a variable inside the $(nk_jonid bsub $VARIABLE)

Answer (score 9):

Nils and Andrey have the answers to this specific question in shell and C/C++ environments respectively.  For the purposes of building dependencies, you can also name your job with -J then build the dependency based on the job name:

```
bsub -J "job1" <cmd1>
bsub -J "job2" <cmd2>
bsub -w "done(job1) && done(job2)" <cmd>
```

There's a bit more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944237/lsf-bsub-how-to-specify-a-single-wrap-up-job-to-be-run-after-all-others-fin).

This also works with job arrays:

```
bsub -J "ArrayA[1-10]" <cmd1>
bsub -J "ArrayB[1-10]" <cmd2>
bsub -w "done(ArrayA[3]) && done(ArrayB[5])" <cmd>
```

You can even do element-by-element dependency.  The following job's *i*-th element will only run when the corresponding element in `ArrayB` reaches `DONE` status:

```
bsub -w "done(ArrayB[*])" -J "ArrayC[1-10]" <cmd3>
```

You can find more info on the various things you can specify in `-w` [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_command_ref/bsub.w.1.html?lang=en).

Comment: (+1) Good thing you noticed the actual intent of the question.

Comment: @jsmedmar Actually, it does.  I'll add some detail to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using C++, you can use the [lsblib](http://www.ccs.miami.edu/hpc/lsf/7.0.6/api_ref/), LSF C API to submit jobs. The input and the output are structs. In particular, the output struct contains the job id.

```
#include <lsf/lsbatch.h>    
LS_LONG_INT lsb_submit (struct submit *jobSubReq, struct submitReply *jobSubReply)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view the JOBID after submission, most of the time I will just use bhist or bhist -l to view the running jobs and details.

```
$ bhist
Summary of time in seconds spent in various states:
JOBID   USER    JOB_NAME  PEND    PSUSP   RUN     USUSP   SSUSP   UNKWN   TOTAL
8664    F14r3   sample       2       0    187954  0       0       0       187956
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$jobid = "0"
bsub pwd > $jobid
cat $jobid
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the job id into the name of the log file.

```
bsub -oo '%J' <rest of your command>
```

a log file will appear in the current directory that is the job id. You can then do what you want.

there are other values you can use besides %J. have a look at the bsub man page.

simple example:

```
> for job in {1..4} ; do bsub -oo '%J' sleep 1s ; done
> bjobs -o 'id cresreq' *
JOBID COMBINED_RESREQ
13217166 select[(type = any ) && (hi&&type == any )] order[r15s:pg]
13217167 select[(type = any ) && (hi&&type == any )] order[r15s:pg]
13217169 select[(type = any ) && (hi&&type == any )] order[r15s:pg]
13217170 select[(type = any ) && (hi&&type == any )] order[r15s:pg]
```