# LSF (bsub): how to specify a single "wrap-up" job to be run after all others finish?

Tags: cluster-computing, lsf

**BASIC PROBLEM:** I want to submit *N* + 1 jobs to an LSF-managed Linux cluster in such a way that the (*N* + 1)-st "wrap-up" job is not run until all the preceding *N* jobs have finished.

**EXTRA:** *If possible*, it would be *ideal* if I could arrange matters so that the (*N* + 1)-st ("wrap-up") job receives, as its first argument, a value of 0 (say) if all the previous *N* jobs terminated successfully, and a value different from 0 otherwise.

This problem (or at least the part labeled "BASIC PROBLEM") is *vastly simpler* than what LSF's `bsub` appears to be designed to handle, so I have a hard time wading through the voluminous documentation for `bsub` to figure out the simplest way to do what I want to do.

> What would be the simplest `bsub` commands to achieve this arrangement?

---

To be more concrete, what would I have to replace the various `???` slots below to ensure that `wrapup` is executed only after all the `foo` jobs have finished (ideally with an argument that reflects the ending status of the `foo` jobs)?

```
bsub -q someq ??? foo 1
bsub -q someq ??? foo 2
bsub -q someq ??? foo 3
bsub -q someq ??? wrapup [???]
```

Comment: job dependencies?  
bsub -J 'myjob[1-10]' mycmd;  
bsub -w myjob wrapup;  
bjdepinfo -l <jobid>

Answer (score 12):

To expand on Michael Closson's answer, what you're looking for here is bsub's -w option, which allows you to submit a job that will only be scheduled if some dependency condition is met.

The most common conditions to use is the exit status of some other job, if you name each of your "foo $i" jobs with -J:

```
bsub -q someq -J "job_1" foo 1
bsub -q someq -J "job_2" foo 2
bsub -q someq -J "job_3" foo 3
```

Then you can submit another job that depends on the exit status of these jobs as follows:

```
bsub -q someq -w "done(job_1) && done(job_2) && done(job_3)" wrapup
```

This tells LSF to only schedule "wrapup" if the jobs named job_1, job_2, and job_3 terminate with DONE status.  You can also use job-id's instead of job names, or specify the specific status you want to test for with expressions like

```
done("job_1")   // termination status is DONE
exit("job_1")   // termination status is EXIT
ended("job_1")  // termination status is EXIT or DONE
```

And combine these with logical operators &&, ||, !

Comment: what if job_1 is an array job_1[1-1000], would all the jobs in the array have to be complete for done("job_1") to evaluate to true?

Comment: @par Yes, I think so.  You can write dependency on a particular element using syntax like "done(job_1[27])" to depend on a particular element, or you can have a pointwise dependency where each element of array job_2[1-1000] can depend on the corresponding element of job_1 by using "done(job_1[*])" in job_2's dependency expression.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094035/lsf-get-id-of-submitted-job/18768066#18768066).