# script to log the completion of an LSF (bsub) job

Tags: cron, heredoc, lsf

I have a script called by cron to run an LSF job.

I would like to be told when that job is submitted and when it completes.  The-Powers-That-Be have decided to disable email notifications.  So I am writing this script to output the relevant information to a logfile.

It *almost* works.  Here is some code:

**crontab:**

```
00 12 * * * my_script.sh my_job.bsub
```

**my_job.bsub:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -q my_queue
#BSUB -W 06:00

echo "I am a long process"
sleep 60
```

**my_script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

BSUB_SCRIPT=$1

# run bsub_script (and get the LSF job id while you're at it)...
JOB_ID=`bsub < $BSUB_SCRIPT | awk -F[\<,\>] '{print $2}'`

# log that job was submitted...                
echo "`date +%Y-%m%d %T` submitted '$BSUB_SCRIPT' [$JOB_ID]" >> $HOME/my_logfile.txt

# and log when job completes...
bsub -w "ended($JOB_ID)" << EOF
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -q my_queue
#BSUB -W 00:30

echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d %T` completed '$BSUB_SCRIPT' [$JOB_ID]" >> $HOME/my_logfile.txt

EOF
```

(I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746666/1060339) helpful in figuring out how to submit a job that waits until an earlier one has completed.)

The issue is that the 2nd call to `date`, in the heredoc, gets evaluated *immediately*, so I wind up with a logfile that looks like this:

**my_logfile.txt:**

```
2018-01-30 13:15:14 submitted 'my_job.bsub' [1234567]
2018-01-30 13:15:14 completed 'my_job.bsub' [1234567]
```

Notice how the times are exactly the same.

How can I ensure that evaluation of the content of the heredoc is deferred until the LSF job runs?

Comment: As is my custom, the answer comes to me once I ask my question: I can do it using 2 scripts.  So instead of a heredoc, the final bsub line would be something like: `bsub -w "ended($JOB_ID)" my_other_script.sh "completed '$BSUB_SCRIPT' [$JOB_ID]"`  And _that_ script would call date and output to the logfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date` command in the heredoc is being expanded before being passed to `bsub`.  You need to quote the `EOF` in your heredoc expression or escape the `date` command.  See the answer to this question:
[How does "cat << EOF" work in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash)

In particular:

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>       <<[-]word
>               here-document
>       delimiter
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If **word** is unquoted, all lines of the **here-document** are
>   subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic
>   expansion.

So, for example when I run

```
$ cat << EOF
> echo `date`
> EOF
```

The output is

```
echo Tue Jan 30 11:57:32 EST 2018
```

Note that the `date` command is expanded, which is what's happening in your script.  However, if I quote the delimiter in the heredoc:

```
$ cat << "EOF"
> echo `date`
> EOF
```

You get the unexpanded output you want:

```
echo `date`
```

Similarly, escaping date would preserve the other variables you want to expand:

```
$ cat << EOF
> echo \$(date)
> EOF
```

Output:

```
echo $(date)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That pointed me in the right direction.  Because I use other script variables in the heredoc, I wound up _not_ quoting ''EOF'' and escaping the "date" function as follows: ```echo "\$(date +%Y-%m-%d %T) completed '$BSUB_SCRIPT' [$JOB_ID]" >> $HOME/my_logfile.txt```  

Yours is still a correct answer.

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer to include that solution as well.