# question on using bwait to wait for multiple bsub jobs to finish

Tags: bash, shell, lsf

I am new to using LSF (been using PBS/Torque all along).

I need to write code/logic to make sure all bsub jobs finish before other commands/jobs can be fired.

Here is what I have done: I have a master shell script which calls multiple other shell scripts via bsub commands. I capture the job ids from bsub in a log file and I need to ensure that all jobs get finished before the downstream shell script should execute its other commands.

Master shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

...Code not shown for brevity..

"Command 1 invoked with multiple bsubs" > log_cmd_1.txt

Need Code logic to use bwait before downstream Commands can be used

"Command 2 will be invoked with multiple bsubs" > log_cmd_2.txt

and so on
```

stdout captured from Command 1 within the Master Shell script is stored in log_cmd_1.txt which looks like this

```
Submitting Sample 101
Job <545> is submitted to .
Submitting Sample 102
Job <546> is submitted to .
Submitting Sample 103
Job <547> is submitted to .
Submitting Sample 104
Job <548> is submitted to .
```

I have used the codeblock shown below after Command 1 in the master shell script.

However, it does not seem to work for my situation. Looks like I would have gotten the whole thing wrong below.

```
while sleep 30m;
do
    #the below gets the JobId from the log_cmd_1.txt and tries bwait

    grep '^Job' <path_to>/log_cmd_1.txt | perl -pe 's!.*?<(\d+)>.*!$1!' | while read -r line; do res=$(bwait -w "done($line)");echo $res; done 1>
<path_to>/running.txt;
    # the below sed command deletes lines that start with Space
    sed '/^\s*$/d' running.txt > running2.txt;
    # -s file check operator means "file is not zero size"
    if [ -s $WORK_DIR/logs/running2.txt ]
        then
            echo "Jobs still running";
        else
            echo "Jobs complete";
            break;
    fi
done
```

The question: What's the correct way to do this using bwait within the master shell script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/46312/wait-for-one-or-all-lsf-jobs-to-complete

Answer (score 2):

`bwait` will block until the condition is satisfied, so the loops are probably not neecessary.  Note that since you're using `done`, if the job fails then bwait will exit and inform you that the condition can never be satisfied. Make sure to check that case.

What you have *should* work.  At least the following test worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

# "Command 1 invoked with multiple bsubs" > log_cmd_1.txt
( bsub sleep 0; bsub sleep 0 ) > log_cmd_1.txt

# Need Code logic to use bwait before downstream Commands can be used
while sleep 1
do
    #the below gets the JobId from the log_cmd_1.txt and tries bwait

    grep '^Job' log_cmd_1.txt | perl -pe 's!.*?<(\d+)>.*!$1!' | while read -r line; do res=$(bwait -w "done($line)");echo "$res"; done 1> running.txt;
    # the below sed command deletes lines that start with Space
    sed '/^\s*$/d' running.txt > running2.txt;
    # -s file check operator means "file is not zero size"
    if [ -s running2.txt ]
        then
            echo "Jobs still running";
        else
            echo "Jobs complete";
            break;
    fi
done
```

Another way to do it. Which may is a little cleaner, is to use job arrays and job dependencies.  Job arrays will combine several pieces of work that can be managed as a single job. So your

```
"Command 1 invoked with multiple bsubs" > log_cmd_1.txt
```

could be submitted as a single job array.  You'll need a driver script that can launch the individual jobs.  Here's an example driver script.

```
$ cat runbatch1.sh 
#!/bin/bash

# $LSB_JOBINDEX goes from 1 to 10
if [ "$LSB_JOBINDEX" -eq 1 ]; then

  # do the work for job batch 1, job 1

  ...

elif [ "$LSB_JOBINDEX" -eq 2 ]; then

  # etc
  ...

fi
```

Then you can submit the job array like this.

```
bsub -J 'batch1[1-10]' sh runbatch1.sh
```

This command will run 10 job array elements.  The driver script's environment will use the variable `LSB_JOB_INDEX` to let you know which element the driver is running.  Since the array has a name, `batch`, it's easier to manage.  You can submit a second job array that won't start until all elements of the first have completed successfully. The second array is submitted with this command.

```
bsub -w 'done(batch1)' -J 'batch2[1-10]' sh runbatch2.sh
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Hi @Micheal, 

Your answer is very useful - I haven't yet tried your 2nd way of doing things. I thought the 1st way (which I posted in my question) should work, but something keeps breaking and it coming out of the loop

Probably, it could be because of the use of _done_ as you explain.

I am now experimenting a 3rd way - I am trying to capture all JobIds using the _grep|perl_ I posted, then converting the multi-line string to a single line and joining all of them with &&

_bwait -w 'ended(jobid1)' && 'ended(jobid2)' &&_  so on as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746666/10101904

Comment: @Miheal -   What's the correct way to use the _-r_ flag with bwait

Is it  like the below (check every 5 mins with -r)

bwait -r 5 -w 'ended(1)' && -r 5 'ended(2)' && so on 

or 

bwait -r 5 -w 'ended(1)' && 'ended(2)' && so on

Comment: Just 1 `-r` per call to bwait.

Comment: A typo `LSB_JOB_INDEX` in your explanation rather than `LSB_JOBINDEX`?